# input type=numberの入力チェックについて

Tags: html5, internet-explorer

HTML5で入力フォームを作成したのですが、type=numberとしたinputタグにおいて、特定の数値が入力チェックに引っかかります。
Windows7(64bit)、Windows10(64bit)で確認したところ、以下の状況となっています。

- Windows7 IE11では「有効な値を入力してください」というメッセージが表示され、送信できません。
- Windows7にインストールした、Firefox、Chromeではデータを送信できます。
- Windows10 IE11およびEdgeでは、データを送信できます。

再現するHTMLを記載します。

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><form>
<input type="number" value="52429.2" step="0.1">
<input type="number" value="6990.73" step="0.01">
<input type="number" value="524.305" step="0.001">
<button type="submit">GO</button></form></body></html>
```

上記の数値ではメッセージが出るのですが、step分を増減するとメッセージが出なくなります。
上記のほかにも、52429.7などで同様のメッセージが出ています。

ひとまず、JavaScriptを経由することで回避できそうなので、私にとっての緊急性はなくなったのですが、
HTMLのみでは、どのように実装すればよかったのでしょうか。
属性の設定が漏れているのか、IE11の挙動としてこういうのがあるのか分かりませんでした。

よろしくお願いいたします。

※Microsoftのフォーラムで同じ質問を投げましたが、回答を得られませんでした。マルチポストになります、すみません。
https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/input/9ae12b00-5136-4e69-8190-ecc59fe3af1e

Comment: ここに記載されている、過去のFirefoxのように http://srad.jp/~minet/journal/582390 「内部値が浮動小数点数のまま実装」されている、ということなのでしょうか。 （コメント編集済み：冗長な部分を削除しました）

Answer (score 7, accepted):

これがWindows7 IE11の[バグ](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/850187/html5-constraint-validation-is-broken-in-ie11-for-input-type-number)です。
Windows10でThreshold 2 / Version 1511 / Build 10586にてフィクスされましたが、Windows7ではそのまま残ってしまいました。

Javascriptを経由しなくて実装したい場合、valueもstepも小数点以下4桁まで記述してください。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><form>
<input type="number" value="52429.2001" step="0.0001">
<input type="number" value="6990.7301" step="0.0001">
<input type="number" value="524.3051" step="0.0001">
<button type="submit">GO</button></form></body></html>
```

Comment: 初期状態が空で、ユーザが入力する場合
'<input type="number" value="" step="0.1">'
'<input type="number" value="" step="0.0001">'
stepを小数点以下4桁にしても、やはり52429.2と入力するとエラーになってしまいます。
このバグは放置されたままになるのでしょうか…

Comment: Windows7でこのバグをフィクスする見込みはなさそうです。  Javascriptを利用して、この問題を回避するしかありません。